# How to replace a column of a CSV file with lines from another file in BASH?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a 4-column CSV file, `data.csv` using "@" as the separator, e.g.:

```
1@fish@ocean@likes to swim in the ocean
2@whale@ocean@likes to swim in the ocean
```

To edit just the 4th column, I used this command:

```
awk -F "@*" '{print $4}' data.csv > temp.csv
```

Then I ran some additional scripts to modify `temp.csv`.

Now, I need to return the contents of `temp.csv` to `data.csv`, replacing everything in the 4th column of `data.csv`.

How can I replace the contents of the 4th column of `data.csv` with the edited lines in `temp.csv`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `paste` and `cut`:

```
cut -d@ -f1-3 data.csv | paste -d@ - temp.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted the other answer, but to give you an idea of the approach in awk:

Having first prepared your `temp.csv` file:

```
$ cut -d@ -f4 data.csv | sed -e 's,ocean,lava,g' > temp.csv
```

You then read a line from `temp.csv` as you read each line from `data.csv`, overwriting the fourth field in the line:

```
$ awk -F@ -vOFS=@ '{ getline $4 < "temp.csv" ; print }' data.csv
1@fish@ocean@likes to swim in the lava
2@whale@ocean@likes to swim in the lava
```

Comment: Or, even easier, `sed 's/\(.*@\)\(.*\)ocean\(.*\)/\1\2lava\3/g' data.csv` (no need for a temporary file).